# loading failed in installing R package fdaPDE from github

Tags: r, rtools

Good morning,

I am trying to install the R package fdaPDE from GitHub repository "NegriLuca/fdaPDE-manifold" via RStudio1.4, using the package devtools. My OS is Windows 10, I am using Rtools35 and R3.5.1. The package has to be compiled from source. I have typed the following:

```
    install.packages('devtools')
    library(devtools)
    install_github("NegriLuca/fdaPDE-manifold")
```

and got the following:

```
    [… I omit the long compilation part …]
    ** building package indices
    ** testing if installed package can be loaded
    *** arch - i386
    Error: package or namespace load failed for 'fdaPDE'inlibrary.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):
    DLL 'fdaPDE' not found: maybe not installed for this architecture?
    Errore: loading failed
    Esecuzione interrotta
    *** arch - x64
    Error: package or namespace load failed for 'fdaPDE' in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):
    DLL 'fdaPDE' not found: maybe not installed for this architecture?
    Errore: loading failed
    Esecuzione interrotta
    ERROR: loading failed for 'i386', 'x64'
    * removing 'C:/Users/Gianmaria/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/fdaPDE'
    In R CMD INSTALL
    Error in i.p(...) : 
    (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/GIANMA~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpwDxgqJ/file466865be7d8c/fdaPDE_0.1-5.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: [This thread](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/170) would indicate updating packages might work.

Comment: I updated all packages, but had the same error while installing

Comment: Do you have `fdaPDE` package installed?

Comment: No, fdaPDE is the library I'm trying to install. Compilation seem to proceed, but the loading test fails

Answer (score 0):

I have finally managed to install the package. What I did was the following:

-REMOVE previous installations (I had supposed that to be done automatically but it was not, and I had an older version installed) by typing in Rstudio

```
remove.packages("fdaPDE")
```

-In Windows cmd, after having downloaded the code from Github, type

```
"Path/to/Rfolder/R" CMD BUILD <path to folder fdaPDE>

"Path/to/Rfolder/R" CMD INSTALL -l <path name of the R library tree> <path name of the package to be installed>
```

Hope that this may be useful for other people who faces similar errors.